# How to switch between DNS suffixes using CMD (netshell)?

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, dns, tcpip

at my job, I have to manually switch between:

*1) append primary and connection specific DNS suffixes and*

*2) Append parent suffixes of the primary DNS suffix*

a bunch of times per day (due to a secure network). 
I'd like to create a .bat to do it automatically, but I can't find the correct Netshell command to do it...

Do you know how can i switch between those options?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I see in the screenshot that you use Windows 7. In more recent versions there are `Set-DnsClient`, `Set-DnsClientGlobalSetting` and other powershell commands to handle dns client settings. I'm not sure if they are available on Win 7.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no netshell command for this.
However, the list is stored in the registry under this path:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
```

You can use the following command from the command line to set the list values:

```
reg add HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters /v "SearchList" /d "example1.com,example2.com" /f
```

Note that the "list" is a comma-separated string, so replace `example1.com,example2.com` with your suffixes.

To revert back to the option "Append primary and connection specific DNS suffixes", simply set the list (the value after /d) to an empty string ("").